# fn.extend not getting selector from this

Tags: jquery

I have a fn.extend function like so

```
$.fn.extend({
    sval: function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        if(val == '' || val == undefined) $(this).val();
        var elem = $(this).children().first();
        if (val == '' || val == undefined) val = $(elem).text();
        if (val == '' || val == undefined) val = $(elem).val();   
        return val;
    }
});
```

this is my first extend function which I am using to try to get the text of an object whether it is input or span or p or other text bearing object.

this works in a couple different functions like this one

```
function rowObj(item, pre){
//check if this is a tr
var tag = item.tagName;
var row = item;
if(pre == undefined){
    pre = '';
}
if(tag != 'TR'){
    row = $(item).closest('tr');
}
var obj = {};
$(row).find('.rowcell').each(function(){
    var keystr = $(this).attr('class');
    var keyarr = keystr.split(" ");
    var key = keyarr[0];
    obj[pre+key] = $(this).sval();
});
return obj;
```

}

sorry about my indent copy and past isnt preserving it, but anyways this works my extend go to its child and gets the value
this is what confuses me
if I try to use sval() on the object I need the value from rather then its parent object it returns with no value. when I try to console.log(this) in sval i get

```
console.log(val)
//$('.invsearch').sval()
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".invsearch", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function…]

//$(item).sval(); --- item is from <input class="invsearch" oninput="searchinv(this)"/>
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function…]
```

In both cases using .val() on "this" does not work from inside sval, I'm sure its simple what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually using the value of an input this is called on:

```
if(val == '' || val == undefined) $(this).val();
```

if we reformat this (one of many reasons to hate one-liners; easy to hide bugs):

```
if (val == '' || val == undefined) 
  $(this).val();
```

you're not actually *using* that value, so `val` is still empty, and we go in search of the children's values.

Try:

```
if (val == '' || val == undefined) 
  val = $(this).val();
```

Comment: thank you I completely missed that lol I have been staring at this all last night and that went over my head I'll mark you answer as the right one as soon as The time limit expires...(why is there a timelimit on how long i have to wait to accept answers)

Comment: Discussed here (not endorsing the rule, just noting the discussion): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer